# No unbounded real continuous function on $X$ can be extended to a continuous real function on $\beta X$

Tags: general-topology, compactness

By the Čech-Stone compactification theorem, I know that if $X$ is Tychonoff and $f:X\to [a,b]$ is continuous then $f$ can be extended to $\hat{f}:\beta X\to [a,b]$.

How can we show that no unbounded real continuous function on $X$ can be extended to a continuous real function on $\beta X$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $A$ is a compact space then $f\colon A\to\Bbb R$ continuous has a bounded range.

Comment: Is it true that this proposition is satisfied for every compactification (for example one-point compactification)?

Comment: @George: Nowhere in the argument we use the $\beta X$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of $X$. Just that it's a compactification.